# Select2 in Sharepoint Application Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Have a Sharepoint application Page where I use Select2 4.0 for Searchable Dropdown List. 
On my development PC everythink works fine but on any Client the CSS seems to be broken (Both use IE11). 
On the Server:

[image: On the Server]

and on the Client it looks like this:

[image]

I use this Code in my Page:

```
 <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/_layouts/15/KartseinTut/Select2.css" runat="server" ID="Select2CssRegistration" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/KartseinTut/jquery.js">
</script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/KartseinTut/Select2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {          
       $('select').select2();
    });
</script>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to check the [browser console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255006(v=vs.85).aspx) on your Client machine to see what errors are being shown there. You can check into that and if you don't get through then update your question with those errors so others can look into.

Comment: I Checked the console I noticed [SEC7115](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh180764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) do you know how to fix this error?

Comment: I am not aware of this error. You should probably update your question to include this error and a screenshot so that others can also look into it.